# Resource bundle in external library not found when running JUnit in via Ant

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have the following scenario:

JUnit tests against some test classes that test app classes. The app classes rely on a library with some resource bundles inside them. The library itself is included in classpath for tests with

```
<classpath>
    <!-- all modules -->
    <path refid="lib.app_modules.path" />
    ...
```

Where

```
<path id="lib.app_modules.path">
    <path location="${myLib}" />
            ...
```

Effect: All classes in the library are found by app classes **BUT** not the resource bundles along them (loaded from inside the library).

Comment: Are you using those resources yourself or the library fails to load its own resources?

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" (or workaround):

Change:

```
<path id="lib.app_modules.path">
    <path location="${myLib}" />
       ...
```

to:

```
<path id="lib.app_modules.path">
    <pathelement path="${myLib}"/>
```

and everything runs fine. Somehow *path* beneath *path* seems to include only classes whereas *pathelement* seems to include everything inside the jar...